# sending updated value to API with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an API that gets `count`. whenever user clicks on `IconButton` I must send the `count` to my server, but it always sends previous value. like if `count` is 1 it sends 0.

```
  const { fetchCalculatedService, response } = useCalcService();
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);


 <IconButton
          color="success"
          disabled={!selectInsurance}
          onClick={() => {
            setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
            fetchCalculatedService(
              Date,
              Id,
              filter,
              Time,
              count
            );
          }}
        >
          <ArrowUpward />
 </IconButton>
```

I logged my `response` and my `count` as well. the `count` is the lastest count and everthing is ok but API response shows `0` in count.

I also looked at server logs. API receives `0`

shouldn't it get latest value of `count` whenever I call it? because value updated before `fetchCalculatedService` invoke

Comment: How about `setCount((prev) => ++prev);`?

Comment: @sm3sher I tried it. still gets 0

Comment: @AES256, Try like `count = count + 1` in the last line of `fetchCalculatedService` . Here `setCount` is an async operation so the updated state won't be available immediately.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan is there anyway to call `fetchCalculatedService` asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to perform the fetch inside the `prev` callback of your state update function. Since react states are being updated async, it `count` is not guaranteed to update immediately after `setCount`.

By fetching inside that callback you can manually raise your `count` variable.

```
<IconButton
  color="success"
  disabled={!selectInsurance}
  onClick={() => {
    setCount((prev) => {
      fetchCalculatedService(Date, Id, filter, Time, prev + 1);
      return prev + 1;
    });
  }}
>
  <ArrowUpward />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: can you explain the `return prev+1` part? what it does?

Comment: Sure. Since you still want to update your state, you need to return something inside that function. The return value will be your updated `count` state.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your count state changed but component is not rerendered yet

you can handle it in this way :

```
 onClick={() => {
        setCount((prev) => {
          fetchCalculatedService(
            Date,
            Id,
            filter,
            Time,
            prev + 1
          );
          return prev + 1
        });

      }}
```